# How Can I Speed This MYSQL Query Up?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MYSQL query for my PHP script. It takes forever to load with how many rows I have in my MYSQL database, but when I remove the line of code it's instant, so for some reason it's taking forever to query.

```
   $res1 = $odb -> query("SELECT SUM(totalbtcdeposited) AS value_sum, SUM(totalltcdeposited) AS value_sum1 FROM referrals WHERE `refid` = '$userid'");
   $row = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $usdamount = $row['value_sum'];
   $usdamount1 = $row['value_sum1'];
```

I have about 8,000 rows in the referrals table and all it is doing is adding numbers together, but it takes forever to run this query, is there an alternative for it or anyway to make it more efficient? Thanks for any help!

`TOP` Output:
[image]

Comment: I would add an index on the table on ( refid, totalbtcdeposited ) and it should fly through.

Comment: And index on 'refid' should help. You should also do some reading here: http://bobby-tables.com/php

Comment: With only 8k rows, the lack of an index is probably not a factor. If you change your query to `SELECT 1 AS value_sum`, does it still "take forever"?

Comment: @DRapp By adding the index through PHPMYADMIN it runs through the script in 5-10 seconds, which is better then 30 seconds.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have changed the SQL in my post to reflect what I had changed.

Comment: @PatrickQ Seeming I have 2 sum values, not sure where to put "Select 1 as..."

Comment: It's just a test to see if your query is actually what's taking so much time. If it doesn't return instantly, then your query isn't the problem.

Comment: @PatrickQ don't add another sum, replace the first one. The aim is to see if the table is slow or if the sum is slow.

Comment: More hardware, more memory, faster cpu and index.  If a table only has 8000 rows and it can't sum in faster than 1 sec you likely have a hardware problem.  what's the CPU utilization when the query is run? too much activity for a small box?

Comment: @JimWright When I wrote my initial comment, the posted query was different (only had one SUM).  OP has since changed it.

Comment: @xQbert Yes I had this assumption to, I have a VPS running 4GB ram and like CPU running 2.4 GHz with ssd. Yes the CPU % goes to around 200-300 % on centos command `top`. I feel as if you could help me more with this info.

Comment: @MeltyNet: Without seeing your whole setup it's nearly impossible to say, but you either have a drastic problem with your PHP logic (you haven't shown us all the code), environment setup, or database design.

Comment: Yep.  The SQL query itself is fine.  The php, connection, or configuration of database/install or the hardware itself has a problem.  perhaps better suited to excahnge serverfault?  need to verify the PHP before a move is requested however.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can speed up the query by adding an index onto the `totalbtcdeposited` and `refid` columns.

   ```
   CREATE INDEX totalbtcdeposited_refid ON referrals (totalbtcdeposited, refid);
   ```
2. If that doesn't make a difference, you should optimize the table.

   ```
   OPTIMIZE TABLE referrals;
   ```
3. If that still doesn't make a difference could you run the query through `EXPLAIN`? It will show how MySQL is running the query.

   ```
   EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(totalbtcdeposited) AS value_sum, SUM(totalltcdeposited) AS value_sum1 FROM referrals WHERE `refid` = '$userid'
   ```

Comment: Adding the index you gave me above didn't work just slowed it down, right now I have seperatly indexed `totalbtcdeposited` `refid` and `totalltcdeposited`. It loads in 11 seconds the whole query. I optimize my tables on the regular, so not the problem. I did the explain function and it didn't display anything.

Comment: How did you run the explain?

Comment: With: `$res1 = $odb -> query("EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(totalbtcdeposited) AS value_sum, SUM(totalltcdeposited) AS value_sum1 FROM referrals WHERE `refid` = '$userid'");
    $row = $res1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` i'm sure that's the wrong way.

Comment: Run it in phpmyadmin. Make sure you swap `userid` for an actual I'd.